# Ejecutar archivo Python con argumento desde código Java

Tags: java, python, macos, terminal

Estoy intentando ejecutar un archivo python dentro de mi código Java. Cuando ejecutó el archivo python desde la terminal de Mac no tengo problema y funciona bien. En la terminal escribo esto

```
python import.py 10477 > out.txt
```

Ese comando funciona correctamente y genera el archivo out.txt, pero cuando lo implemento en Java no realiza la acción. Estoy usando este código;

```
String path = "/Users/Atlas/Desktop/Job/Python";
String textValue = textFixVersion.getText(); # Get value from a TextBox

if(releaseRadio.isSelected()) { # Radio Button

     String terminal = "python import.py " + textValue + " > out.txt";

     try {
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(terminal,null,new File(path));
     }
     catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Atlass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

Ese código me funciona perfectamente cuando ejecutó archivos Jar dentro de mi código java pero con *.py no se ejecuta. Estoy usando Python 3.9.10.

Comment: Podria ser un problema de path. ¿Probaste a colocar el path completo al interprete Python?

Comment: Intenta de este modo: `exec(new String[]{"bash","-c",terminal},null,new File(path));`

Answer (score 2):

En este caso no podrás guardar en un archivo de salida la información usando:

```
" > out.txt"
```

Una opción para guardar el resultado en un archivo es, es ejecutar el comando:

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python", "import.py 10477"));
```

creas un `InputStream` a partir del resultado de la ejecución:

```
  InputStream stdout = mProcess.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

y guardas en un archivo en `InputStream`:

```
try {
            
            File targetFile = new File("C:/Users/Atlas/Desktop/Job/Python/out.txt");
            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = stdout.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                  outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver con la forma de @JonnhyTB:

```
exec(new String[]{"bash","-c",terminal},null,new File(path))
```

Unicamente hay que seleccionar la ruta completa de python3 ya para que use ese interprete. Muchas gracias!!